# PHP landing page on Apache server Cisco WLC controller

Tags: php, cisco, authentication, wifi, captive-portal

I have a landing page done on php along with SQL database for WIFI user registration along with Cisco wireless controller.
The WLC is redirecting the user to the landing page for authentication /  registration. The user logs in successfully but the WLC does not give the internet access as it waits for acknowledgment from the apache server back with information on username / password.

Comment: can you provide more details around the radius deployment.  WLCs will not provide access unless there is a radius return message.  why are you not using you website and radius server?

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue, you will need fix your design. As the WLC will not provide access without radius challenge messages to process the request for Authn and Authz to the network.

1. Deploy a radius server that your website points (Something like FreeRadius will work fine and can be setup with SQL or Cisco ISE)
2. Add the controller to the radius server
3. Add the radius server to the controller

Depending your SSID (Open or encrypted) will define your next steps.